# How to replicate/duplicate tabels in sql server with row data?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, azure-sql-database

i have 3 tables with master data A, B and C in an sql-server.

Based on user-requirements there is a need to replicate these tables, let call replica-tables AA, BB and CC - such that experiments can be done on this replicated data. So i end up with 6 tables in total.

When replication from UI takes place, it shall bring all the master data from A, B, and C for a "fresh start" into AA, BB, CC. Data in AA, BB, CC will then change over time. Then when user selects "Reset data" from UI again it will replicate A, B, C into AA, BB, CC again.

How can this be done in SQL in a good way? I'm using dotnet EF Core.

Comment: You should add sample data to your question.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Does an sql-server mean MS SQL Server?)

Comment: azure sql - so implicit an MS SQL Server i guess

Answer (score 0):

You could try use raw sql to delete table "AA" then create a new "AA" table

```
using (var db = new MyDbContext())
{
     db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("DROP TABLE AA");  //delete table
     db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SELECT * INTO AA FROM A");  //create a new table from A
}
```

Comment: Great, how would that work in-between migrations. Could that cause issues?

Comment: @otk I don't think it will cause issue. Because "AA" table always exist.